# What color should i design my artwork for printing on a black shirt

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

If I'm designing for a black shirt how could i send my design should it be black and im going to instruct them that it should be white or should i make the background black and the design white

Comment: Interesting question. It probably depends on where you're getting it printed, so it's probably a good idea to contact the shop directly and ask them what they would need. My guess is a print file and a reference file (which is what you have outlined in your question).

Answer (score 2):

The T-Shirt printers should be able to provide you with the information.

However, as a general rule for single colour white printing on a dark background you should provide them with the design in BLACK on a white background (reversed), but accompany it with clear instructions and a visual of how you want the shirts to look when the design is printed in white ink.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created the design yourself, you could make the image transparent and coloring your design with the color you've thought of (not dark colors, people will have a hard time reading/looking at it leading to frustration)

But you still need to give instructions so the t-shirt printers would know what the output you envisioned.

Answer (score -1):

If you intend to print white onto black shirts, create the design as such. If you're using photoshop, export with a transparent background.